# Strange behaviour of SearchQuerySet in django-haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack

I need to set up simple search through text by means of django-haystack (2.3.1) and elasticsearch backend (1.4.0).

I have next simple model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

SearchIndex looks like this:

```
class CourseIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(model_attr='price')
```

Template `course_text.txt`:

```
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.description }}
```

As you can see, everything is simple. All I need from haystack is:

`SearchQuerySet.filter(text='zza')` to return me `[ <Course: Pizza> , <Course: Freezza>]` like django orm's `QuerySet` does. But instead, I get nothing. Using `SearchQuerySet.filter(text='pizza')` returns result

Official docs say that starting from 2.0, haystack by default uses `contains` method for filtering. Using it explicitly does not help as well: `SearchQuerySet.filter(text__contains='zza')`

`autocomplete` feature of haystack also did not help, since it works more like `starts_with` method, rather than `contains`.

Then I have also tried to use other backends. I have tested `Whoosh` but got the same result as in `elasticsearch`. Being in desperate, I have plugged in `SimpleBackend` which is only for testing purposes in haystack and it worked!

Please guys, if you have any ideas how to fix this, share with them here.

From my point of view it seems to be a problem in backend configuration which haystack provides for elasticsearch and whoosh.

Thanks

Comment: I have got the same problem. The search works for one of the model but not the other. Did you find any solution? would be a great help!